# Modelio : default stereotypes are unavailable

Tags: stereotype, modelio

I use Modelio 3.2 and i have a problem with default stereotype.

For instance, when i create two use cases and i add an "extends" links in the use cases (on an existing use case diagram, where i already create an "extends" links in the past... without problem), i have the following error :

> E208: The dependency between the ''UseCaseDependency' {f06da9f2-e719-434f-b5cb-8dbf36d692be} UseCaseDependency' and '{1}' use cases is not stereotyped <> or <>.
>
> A UseCaseDependency must be stereotyped <> or <>.

I think the modelio project is corrupted, because i try on an other computer and i have the same error.

How resolve this bug ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Configuration > Modules entry could you check ig the 8.3.00.9022 version of Modeler Module is well started!? If not add it and try again.

[image]

Comment: Now, this bug is the past.

Thank you Red Beard ;)